# Excepción al parsear fecha en java

Tags: java, date, formato, parsear

Estoy parseando fechas con un formato en concreto y por alguna razón que se me está escapando obtengo la excepción unparseable date.

La fecha tiene este formato "19 may 18:30 2018"

Y mi código:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM HH:mm yyyy", new Locale("es","ES"));
calendar.setTime(dateFormat.parse("19 may 18:30 2018"));
```

Comment: ¿Lo tienes dentro de un bloque `try... catch`? A mí no me da error así: **`try {
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM HH:mm yyyy", new Locale("es","ES"));
            calendar.setTime(dateFormat.parse("19 may 18:30 2018"));
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }`**

Comment: Te falta un punto después del nombre del mes (ej. 19 may. 18:30 2018). Este tipo de problemas los puedes detactar haciendo la operación inversa, tomando una fecha y formatearla con el `SimpleDateFormat` que creaste.

Answer (score 0):

> Te falta un punto después del nombre del mes (ej. 19 may. 18:30 2018). Este tipo de problemas los puedes detectar haciendo la operación inversa, tomando una fecha y formatearla con el SimpleDateFormat que creaste. – E. Betanzos

Muchas gracias, en efecto si le añado un "." después del mes lo parsea correctamente